# Visual Studio test explorer requirements run all

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

When I run tests in test explorer individually they all run without errors.

When I click on "Run All" I get varying test that fail.

**My question:** 
Does anybody know what the minimum requirements regarding tests to be able to run them with "Run All"? Like maybe they all have to in a certain way with a certain command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I had a static variable still containing a value other than that expected. Now the outcome is always the same regardless of how I run it.

**Sorry for troubling you all**

Answer (score 0):

Running test manually one by one or run all has nothing to do with your tests being failed. You need to check the failure reason for each test and solve it.

Maybe you can post the error messages here so we can help you better.